# Easy restyling of input type file with javascript + jquery. Css fix needed D: on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

Hello i trying to style the input[type="file"]. But like one old man sayed: "One Jsfiddle is better of 1000 words" so.... here you go

--- More details inside --> http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/4ZuGj/

problem 1 : when i add more files those arent displayed in field...we need to extend it
css solution prefered jquery less favorite ^^
thanks for your help

problem 2 : how to expand the transparent file input to 100% height with position absolute?

```
I thinks the main problem is with position: relative and absolute.....
```

Comment: What is the problem? I see beautiful designed input file...

Comment: Please copy your code also here and describe the problem please :)

Comment: `.upfield input` is your style for that. I dont know if i need to say but its `opacity` is set to 0 btw.

Comment: if you add more and more files the problem appears  Thanks for compliment ^^ Now i going to add more code here. For Batu Zet > i dont want to see the default file input so i decided to hide it ...

Comment: UPdated fiddle whit problem example

Comment: WHO DOWNVOTED MY QUESTION ???! 3:-(O)

Comment: @AgeLonglife Don't use CAPS! ITS SHOUTING!

Comment: Sorry i thought it is good for better reading :) With good intections

Comment: @AgeLonglife - it makes it even worse for reading ;) Your brain actually has trouble reading stuff in capitals. It uses recognition, to try and work out the word. Why is how you skim read ;) I have a client who does ALL his email in capitals - and it drives me up the wall!

Comment: Ok man, i fixed it! And also updated the jsfiddle... can you still help me with this css problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting opacity to 0 on the file input

```
.upfield input[type=file]{
    opacity:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZuGj/4/

Update

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZuGj/5/

For IE also add height:100%

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZuGj/7/

Comment: Hi, the problem isn't opacity but the height of the input...opacity is set to .5 just for show the problem: height doesnt expand with parent.

Comment: Thanks to you one prob. is fixed! If you can help me with the last thing: how i can expand the container. I updated the fiddle for explain better.

Comment: Thanks ^^ I solve it later for now it's just fine :D Because i want to displat the files name not hide...